# Increment field value in update query

Tags: 7, database

I am converting some module from d5 to d7, and in old code there is an update query like this:

```
<?php
db_query("UPDATE {a_table} SET count = count + 1 WHERE field1 = %d", $some_value);
```

As we see, it is incrementing a field value (AFAIK it is a mysql feature).
But, if I use new style of update it won't work.

```
<?php
db_update('a_table')
    ->fields(array('count' => 'count + 1',))
    ->condition('field1', $some_value)
    ->execute();
```

Are there any workaround within new style of db update without running an extra query to get existing field value to increment it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it by adding an [expression](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/function/UpdateQuery%3A%3Aexpression/7) to the query:

```
db_update('a_table')
  ->expression('count', 'count + 1')
  ->condition('field1', $some_value)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Just noting, this also works in Drupal 8